# Converting a date (string) into another date format (string)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a novice question, will be happy if any one out there can help me.

I have an NSMutableArray, for example:

```
{
JobID = 109302930;
Subject = "Test Subject";
SubmitDate = "2009-09-15 17:27:34";
}
```

I am now trying to create sections in my table view and want to group my records based on "formatted" SubmitDate. For example;

```
16th May'09
===========
Item A
Item B

18th May'09
===========
Item C
Item G

20th May'09
===========
Item Z
Item K
```

I am creating this NSMutableArray with the following function (from an XML data source):

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {   
    currentElement = [[NSString alloc] init];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subject"]) {
        [item setObject:currentSubject forKey:@"Subject"];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"job_id"]) {
        [item setObject:currentJobID forKey:@"JobID"];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"submit_date"]) {
        // I want to insert the date value in a formatted way instead of the standard MySQL date format (YYYY-MM-HH).
        [item setObject:currentJobSubmitDate forKey:@"SubmitDate"];
        [previewData addObject:item];
    }
}
```

As I commented in the above code, instead of YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS, I want to add the date as a formatted date string. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do that. You can use it to create an `NSDate`, then use it again to create a differently-formatted string to use.

Comment: Jeff, thanks. Yes, I tried that but didn't work. Using NSDateFormatter, I set the date format (Ex: yyyy-MM-dd) but I'm having problem on NSDate. I am unable to create an NSDate object with a string. Let's say I have an NSString and value is "2009-09-24 01:00:00".

How can I create NSDate object based on this value? Sorry if this is a silly question, newbie here :)

Comment: You'll need to follow four steps:

 1.) Set your `NSDateFormatter`'s `dateFormat` property to what you currently have in string form.

 2.) Use the `-dateFromString:` method of your `NSDateFormatter` to create an `NSDate` object from the string.

3.) Set your `NSDateFormatter`'s `dateFormat` property to match what you want your string to look like in the end.

4.) Use the `-stringFromDate:` method of your `NSDateFormatter` to create your string from your `NSDate`.